# System not exiting in exception

Tags: python, file, exception

I am calling function to open text file. In case of exceptions I want to exit the whole program.
The code is as follows:

```
def get_words():
    print("File:",FILENAME)

    try:
        words = open(FILENAME, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File {} not found.".format(FILENAME))
        sys.exit(1)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Unexpected Error opening {}".format(FILENAME))
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        with words:
            words2 = words.read()
            wordlist = words2.split(" ")

            words.close()
            return wordlist
    pass
```

I am calling this function in the following code:

```
words = get_words()
```

When I execute this, I get error that `During Handling of the above exception, another Exception occured`.
Kindly share that why such simple thing is causing error.
Full traceback:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

File: words1.txt
File words1.txt not found.
>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "397635619.py", line 45, in load_words
    words = open(FILENAME, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'words1.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8232/397635619.py", line 67, in <module>
    wordlist = load_words()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8232/397635619.py", line 48, in load_words
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 248, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 281, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    records = fix_frame_records_filenames(inspect.getinnerframes(etb, context))
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\inspect.py", line 1541, in getinnerframes
    frameinfo = (tb.tb_frame,) + getframeinfo(tb, context)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tb_frame'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please copy the exact code and the complete error. At least your code have some indentation problems

Comment: are you using IPython? This seems to be intended behavior or a known bug (https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12831)

Comment: Yes i m using IPython. How can I execute this function then? To open file and return list from it otherwise exit whole program if exception is raised?

Comment: Exceptions in the code of an `else:` clause of a `try:` statement are *not* handled by the preceding `except` clauses, so you need to handle the `FileNotFoundError` there separately. You could do that via another nested `try`/`except` or by determining whether file exists via `os.path.exists()` *before* attempting to open it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should fix the problem.

```
import sys
import os

def get_words():

    print("File:",FILENAME)
 
    if os.path.exists(FILENAME):
        with open(FILENAME, 'r') as f:
            words2 = f.read()

        return words2.split(" ")
    else:
        print("File {} not found.".format(FILENAME))
        sys.exit()

words = get_words()
```